# How to find two identical pixels (color-value) in two different images with Python

Tags: python, image, dictionary

**My question changed slightly – please see UPDATE below**

I would like to compare two different images with Python. The aim is to find a pixel color value that exists in both images.

I wrote a small program to collect all pixel color values from the images. And at the moment I have a dictionary / output.txt that looks like this:

```
{"pixels": [[232, 251, 255], [231, 250, 254], [230, 249, 253], [230, 249, 252], [230, 250, 251], [230, 249, 254], [230, 249, 255], [230, 250, 255], [228, 250, 254], [228, 249, 254], [228, 249, 254], [229, 248, 252], [230, 249, 253], [230, 249, 253], [231…}
```

Now my question is: How can I compare these values with the values of the other image and see if there are same color values in it?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I would like to update my initial question. I now have two (more or less complex) lists. The first one contains image names and the image pixel colors in hex. So it looks like this:

```
{
0: {'hex': ['#c3d6db', '#c7ccc0', '#9a8f6a', '#8a8e3e'], 'filename': 'imag0'}, 
1: {'hex': ['#705b3c', '#6a5639', '#442f1e', '#4a3d28'], 'filename': 'img-xyz'},
…
}
```

The second dictionary contains a lot of hex-values as keys and an id as value. It looks like:

```
{'#b0a7aa': '9976', '#595f5b': '19367', '#9a8f6a': '24095'…}
```

Now what I would like to do is to look if there is a color-value from my images (first list) that matches with one of the second list. If so, then I would like to know the filename from the first list and the value, the id,  of the matched key in the second list.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Where is the other image's list?

Answer (score 3):

I would first try to convert the list of lists into a set of tuples:

```
>>> t1 = {(r,g,b) for [r,g,b] in p1}
>>> t2 = {(r,g,b) for [r,g,b] in p2}
```

then use the intersection method:

```
>>> t1.intersection(t2)
set([(231, 250, 254)])
```

Comment: Thanks. I know have converted it to a set of tuples. Now I thought it would be better to have them as HEX-Code instead of rgb-values. How could I change all the values easily?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a list of lists from your other program, return a set of tuples  Then you can do

```
set.intersection(pixels(image1), pixels(image2))
```

to find all pixels that exist in both images.